# iFrame and Javascripts

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the following page with iframes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-   
transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">
     alert("test");
     elements = document.getElementById("reference").contentWindow.getElementLength();
     alert("test2");
 </script>
</head>
<frameset cols="20%,*">
   <frameset rows="25%,*">
      <frame src="./groups.html" name="types">
      <frame src="./entities.jsp" name="entities">
   </frameset>
   <frame src="./reference.jsp" name="reference" id="reference">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Inside reference.jsp, I have the following code :

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function getElementLength(){
            alert("in reference");
            elements=document.getElementByClassName("link");
            alert(elements.length);
        }
   </script>
 </head><body>...</body></html>
```

I checked earlier StackOverflow posts about using Javascript across frames and found that contentWindow does the trick but in this case, I only get first alert - "test" and the frame with id="reference" is never reached. I see the following error in Firebug:

```
document.getElementById("reference") is null
elements = document.getElement...").contentWindow.getElementLength();
```

Is there something I am missing, this seems to be a very straighforward usecase.

Comment: Note: these are not iFrames ... just Frames ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that your script is executing before the frame is loaded ...

You could do the following to ensure the frame is loaded before the script is executed :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load() {
     alert("test");
     elements = document.getElementById("reference").contentWindow.getElementLength();
     alert("test2");
}
 </script>

<frameset cols="20%,*">
   <frameset rows="25%,*">
      <frame src="./groups.html" name="types">
      <frame src="./entities.jsp" name="entities">
   </frameset>
   <frame src="./reference.jsp" name="reference" id="reference" onload="load()">
</frameset>
```

I have added the `onload="load()"` attribute in the frame `reference` and wrapped your script in the `load()` function. This will cause the code to be executed once the `reference` frame is loaded.

Comment: I fully agree with @ManseUK.Another small issue is that in reference.jsp the `elements=document.getElementByClassName("link");` instruction must be changed to `elements=document.getElementsByClassName("link");` (with an s) to retrieve all link classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your document type is **transitional** which isn't support the framset
try the below document type tag

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```